# Is it true that nitrate radicals improve air quality during the night (and that is why light pollution, which destroys them, is bad)?

Tags: light, air-pollution

Is it true that nitrate radicals improve air quality during the night (and that is why light pollution, which destroys them, is bad)? I just came across [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://ec.europa.eu/programmes/erasmus-plus/project-result-content/0eb54a4b-9b44-47a1-9acb-c56685ce80c5/Light%2520Pollution%2520%2526%2520Climate%2520Change%2520(Turkey).pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjt-9jv9I37AhVCEncKHVBhCWUQFnoECE0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw1zE-ELmpN86i_M7Zw7PFJD) old presentation on light pollution from the European Commission site, and it seems fascinating. I'd like to know more about it

[image]

Comment: This question probably belongs on Skeptics. Consider moving it.

Comment: ["Ammonium nitrate is a major aerosol constituent over many land regions and contributes to air pollution episodes, ecosystem destruction, regional haze, and aerosol-induced climate forcing."](https://acp.copernicus.org/articles/21/15901/2021/). Also from the same article, NO3 can occurs as either fine or course particles. " ... fine NO3 burdens are concentrated over land, coarse NO3 (i.e. coarseNO3) is more evenly spread over the Earth and prevalent over maritime areas where it forms on sea salt and aged dust particles."

Comment: [Effects of mineral dust on global atmospheric nitrate concentrations](https://acp.copernicus.org/articles/16/1491/2016/), [Particulate nitrate photolysis in the atmosphere](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2022/ea/d1ea00087j). ["Nitrate (NO3−) has been the dominant and the least reduced chemical component of fine particulate matter (PM2.5) since the stringent emission controls implemented in China in 2013"](https://acp.copernicus.org/articles/22/12629/2022/).

Comment: @Fred what do you mean to say?